# Google PageSpeed says "Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content"

Tags: wordpress, css, javascript, page-speed

I own a WordPress site and I am trying to improve my PageSpeed Insights score.  The only "Red" item I have says "Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content"

> **Render Blocking Examples**
>
> ../wp-content/themes/sydney/js/scripts.js,qver=4.7.1
>
> https://s0.wp.com/…ontent/js/devicepx-jetpack.js?ver=201703
>
> https://secure.gravatar.com/js/gprofiles.js?ver=2017Janaa
>
> https://widget.privy.com/assets/widget.js?ver=4.7.1
>
> **Optimize CSS**
>
> https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis
>
> ../wp-content/themes/sydney/css/bootstrap/A.bootstrap.min.css,qver=1
>
> ../wp-content/uploads/siteorigin-widgets/A.sow-hero-default-b34d600c69a5.css
>
> ../wp-content/plugins/ultimate-faqs/css/A.ewd-ufaq-styles.css,qver=4.7.1
>
> ../wp-content/plugins/jetpack/css/A.jetpack.css,qver=4.4.2
>
> https://assets.privy.com/assets/widget-de68f2b744114db673152644e0164ef7b47436c0e1088b3e94d8a443494337bd.css

The above are just some examples. What changes can/should I make to my website to solve this problem?

I have Mod Pagespeed installed so I think that's why some of the URL paths are strange.

Comment: Are you using any cache plugin? If not, then try one.

Comment: This is really to broad to answer specifically. Here's Google's guides on how to [Remove Render-Blocking JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS) and for [CSS](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-blocking-css). There are also tutorials you can search for that are specific to WordPress plugins that might help, depending your site's specific plugins/code, like [this](https://kinsta.com/blog/eliminate-render-blocking-javascript-css/) one.

Comment: You should note that many sites also get this suggestion/warning though, including Google's own [AngularJS](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fangularjs.org%2F) site, so I wouldn't be overly concerned if that's above your abilities to resolve on your own.

Comment: Above the fold content should rely on inline css and html. Importing any external css or js will cause render blocking.